# использование какого падежа будет правильным?

Tags: падежи

как будет правильно: "они ожидали дежурствА" или "они ожидали дежурствО"?

Comment: Задайте реальный вопрос, привязанный к определенной жизненной ситуации. Выбор падежа зависит от того, какое дежурство вы имеете в виду, конкретное (с чем-то связанное) или отвлеченное (дежурство вообще).

Comment: контекст такой: "Следующее ночное дежурство Александр, да и сама Галина Михайловна (медсестра. т.е. речь идет о дежурстве в больнице), ждали с нетерпением." если выбрать вариант "дежурство", получившееся предложение можно понимать и в том смысле, что "во время дежурства Александр и Галина ожидали... (чего именно ожидают - другой вопрос, остающийся непроясненным)".

Comment: Поставим в винительном - рядом будут стоять "дежурство Александр", и не сразу видно, где подлежащее, да и вообще фраза плохо читается. Спотыкач для читателя! Это небольшой плюс в пользу родительного.

Comment: Niemand, согласен с вами )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В словаре управления (Д. Э. Розенталь):
[ожидать](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/1437)
*чего и кого-что*
**1. чего** (при сочетании с отвлеченным существительным или конкретным, но употребленным с оттенком неопределенности).
Ожидать удобного случая. Ожидать прибытия парохода. День целый ожидал я тайного свидания с Мариной (П.). Может быть, ожидаете что-нибудь дурного? (Остр.)
**2. кого-что** (при сочетании с одушевленным существительным или с неодушевленным, но употребленным с оттенком определенности).
Ожидать сестру. Зина подумала о Шурике и Кате, которые, наверно, ожидают маму (Коч.). Ожидать поезд № 56.

Абстрактно:
1. Они с тоской ожидали (чего? Р. п.) дежурства.
2. С волнением он ожидал (что? В. п.) свое первое дежурство в качестве врача-ординатора.

Comment: спасибо.наверное, это и будет ответом на мой вопрос =)

Comment: @Сережа Вам дали хороший ответ. Если он действительно помог Вам разобраться, поставьте галочку слева от ответа (засчитать ответ) и нажмите там же треугольник вверх (поставить плюс за ответ).

Comment: @Сережа Если будете заниматься вандализмом, Вы их никогда не получите. Зачем Вы аккуратно отредактированный вопрос вернули обратно к своим ошибкам? Ведь знаете хотя бы, что предложение начинается с прописной буквы?

Comment: грамматических ошибок я не допускал. и я не вижу, чем предложенные другими пользователями варианты редакции МОЕГО вопроса лучше чем тот, который использовал я. Да, я знаю о прописмных буквах, но при этом не считаю их использование в интернете (если только речь не идет об официальном обращениив какие-либо органихзации) обязательным. И насчет баллов - мне они не нужны. И если вы ограничиваете новичков в оценке ответов на их вопросы - это трудности администрации сайта, а не мои.

Comment: @grizzly Спасибо за поддержку.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Всё никак не выберу повод сказать: будь моя воля, я бы выделил специальный приз для Вас за правку вопросов. Никто другой из нас не делает это так хорошо. Поэтому сейчас меня действительно задело.

Comment: @grizzly Премного благодарна за оценку — добрые слова всем приятны.